# Multiplicação de matrizes

Tags: python, python-3.x

Poderiam dar um help com Matriz em python?! 
O exercício é o seguinte, uma função `matriz_mult(n1, n2)` recebe duas matrizes como parâmetro e devolve `True` se as matrizes forem multiplicavéis na ordem dada e `False` caso contrário.

A saída deve ser algo do tipo :

```
n1 = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]
n2 = [[2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7]]
matriz_mult(n1, n2) => False

n1 = [[1], [2], [3]]
n2 = [[1, 2, 3]]
matriz_mult(n1, n2) => True
```

Comment: Essa pergunta já tem uma resposta. Dê uma pesquisada. Estou no celular e não tenho como achá-la agora.

Comment: A memória é capaz de me estar a falhar, mas o que queres dizer com: "...forem multiplicavéis na ordem dada"?

Comment: O problema começa entendendo o princípio matemático. O que diz que duas matriz são multiplicáveis?

Comment: Se você já sabe o princípio matemático, leia sobre a função [`len`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#len) do Python.

Comment: @Wiker, desculpe mas nao localizei, tinha achado algo referente a soma de matrizes apenas.
@A

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Matematicamente, duas matrizes são multiplicáveis se o número de colunas da primeira for igual ao número de linhas da segunda.

Considerando que suas matrizes estejam no formato:

```
n1 = [
  [1, 2, 3],
  [4, 5, 6]
]
```

Sendo que `n1` é uma matriz 2x3, obtemos o número de colunas fazendo:

```
n1_cols = len(n1[0])
```

E obtêm-se o número de linhas de `n2` fazendo:

```
n2_rows = len(n2)
```

Basta, então verificar de os valores são iguais:

```
def matriz_mult(n1, n2):
    n1_cols = len(n1[0])
    n2_rows = len(n2)
    return (n1_cols == n2_rows)
```

Veja funcionando no [Repl.it](https://repl.it/GDK3/0).

Comment: Anderson sua resposta resolve de forma muito simples com o uso do "len" Obrigado!

Answer (score 1):

Na verdade quando vc expressa:

```
n1 = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]
n2 = [[2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7]]
```

Voce esta apenas "representando" matrizes, mas na realidade voce está trabalhando com listas. Em python, para trabalhar com matrizes verdadeiras voce poderia usar numpy. Para resolver o que vc propoe eu faria uma função assim:

```
import numpy as np

def mult_array(n1, n2):
    m1 = np.array(n1)
    m2 = np.array(n2)
    try:
        dot(m1,m2)
        success = True
    except:
        success = False        
return success
```

Então voce poderia chama-la:

```
print (mult_array(n1,n2))
```

Que resultaria False, ou

```
n3 = [[5,6,7,8][1,2,3],[9,8,7]]
print (mult_array(n1,n3)
```

Que resultaria: True.

Comment: Opa! Então, até tentei usar o numpy, porem o programa de correção automática acaba gerando erro. 
Sua ideia também é valida, eu devia ter especificado que não poderia usar o import.
Mesmo assim obrigado!

Comment: @nexus, quando vc diz que o "programa de correção automatica acaba gerando erro", voce quer dizer o editor? Voce tem o numpy instalado? Para saber tente os comandos abaixo:


    python -c "import numpy; print(numpy.__path__)"

ou

    python -c "import numpy; print(numpy.__version__)"

Para instalar:

    pip install numpy

Comment: nao nao, é um programa que realiza correção mesmo. Assim ele acaba não conseguindo realizar o import.
Estou ciente dos comandos.